# Looking to create a "Terms and Conditions" page for our Company's Sharepoint Intranet

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I've taken over an Office 365 admin role (using SharePoint Online 2013 in particular here) and we're in the middle of a data migration. I was asked to look into displaying a Terms and Conditions page for users logging in after a change.

After some research it seems the best recommended course of action is to create a User property and set to false and create a User control on a page to check the property and if false, redirect to the Ts&Cs page and once accepted change to true for user.

However I haven't done much more than assign user permissions through AD security groups in SharePoint and have a feeling this is far and away more advanced.

Does anyone have a Technet article or tutorial to show me where to begin with this, a lot of what I'm reading says I should be very comfortable with building and deploying Web Parts via SharePoint (spoiler, I'm not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done anything like that with regards to making a user accept a new version of Ts&Cs, but I have made users accept Ts&Cs based on a cookie. The cookie woud expire after a set amount of time. Check out http://www.cookiecentral.com/code/js_code.htm

Comment: We did something similar.  We have a java user agreement pop-up that is embedded into a script editor web part.  When people launch their browser, they have to click ok to close.  The cookie is persistent as long tas they keep their browser open.