# SharePoint Site Terms of Agreement Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps

Need to add a terms of agreement page on the SP online site, where each user have to agree to the terms of use, until they do so we need to lock the site for them and show them policy page.

The problem is, if some people have documents from the site bookmarked from the site, they can access those documents. How to block that access until the user accessing that document hasn't accepted the terms of use for the site

Comment: Did you implement it via AZureAD terms of user with Conditional access? what is the expiry date you set to start with.

Comment: Can we use that for a particular SharePoint Online site ?

Comment: did you follow this "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/terms-of-use" to implement the terms of use. if you properly configured then next sign in required this

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the SetCookie function in your page.

```
function SetCookie (name, value) {
         var argv = SetCookie.arguments;
         var argc = SetCookie.arguments.length;
         var expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null;
         var path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : null;
         var domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null;
         var secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
         document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
         ((expires == null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toGMTString())) +
         ((path == null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) +
         ((domain == null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) +
         ((secure == true) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function setC(form) {
   var expdate = new Date ();
   expdate.setTime (expdate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 31));
   SetCookie (form.name, form.value, expdate);
}
```

Similar question is answered here:

[Looking to create a “Terms and Conditions” page for our Company's Sharepoint Intranet](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172865/looking-to-create-a-terms-and-conditions-page-for-our-companys-sharepoint-int)

For Cookie java script details, please refer [this](http://www.cookiecentral.com/code/js_code.htm).

Another approach for the same from this thread [create agreement page in SharePoint site:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5fe35298-a135-4dc8-a233-e9f61402b32e/create-agreement-page-in-sharepoint-site?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)

To do it right, you would probably best go with an FBA kind of approach.  Your custom membership provider could determine whether the user has accepted before and then take the right action.

A second best approach (or at least another approach) would be to insert some jQuery into a common master page that performs this check.  The drawback, of course, is that it will be running all the time someone hits a page.

I can think of other more fancy approaches.  You could have a custom asp page that goes and provisions their account after they accept.  That would relatively complicated.

Comment: How can we stop users access to the documents link which are stored previously as a bookmark in the browsers ? those links still tend to open up